# Heroku doesn't load images, though they are precompiled and the url (in html) is correct

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have trouble with images, I use assets_path in the views to figure out the final path to images (employee photos). Then I let Heroku precompile all the assets on pushing repo. It worked right before, but now the photos are not showing.

What's more bizarre, while running app, html is generated right (as seen in the view page source... the photo src urls can be copied and pasted into browser and they retrieve the right assets!) but the photos are not showing on page.

Here's the view. 'assets_path' is used to determine the final path after precompiling:

```
<ol class="employees_list">
  <% employees.each do |employee| %>
  <li>
     <%= link_to employee_path(employee) do %>
       <div data-picture data-alt="Photo of <%= employee.name %>" class="photo">
         <% if employee.photo %>
           <div data-src="<%= asset_path employee.photo %>"></div>
           <div data-src="<%= asset_path employee.photo('small', 2) %>" data-media="(min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"></div>
           <noscript>
             <img src="<%= asset_path employee.photo %>" alt="Photo of <%= employee.name %>">
           </noscript>
         <% end %>
       </div>
     <% end %>
  </li>
 <% end %>
</ol>
```

What's strange, Heroku output html looks like this (fragment - one list item) :

```
<li>
    <a href="/employees/586">
      <div data-picture data-alt="Photo of Marcy Dakss" class="photo">
        <div data-src="/assets/employees/small/marcy_dakss-84bb6d3482d0af4667d24f8cd7017c7f.jpg"></div>
        <div data-src="/assets/employees/small/marcy_dakss@2x-de98d9acfea2e840aa039854c385007b.jpg" data-media="(min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"></div>
        <noscript>
          <img src="/assets/employees/small/marcy_dakss-84bb6d3482d0af4667d24f8cd7017c7f.jpg" alt="Photo of Marcy Dakss">
        </noscript>
      </div>
    </a>  
</li>
```

...now when you copy and paste the asset url in  to the browser tag by hand (/assets/employees/small/marcy_dakss-84bb6d3482d0af4667d24f8cd7017c7f.jpg), the photo is displayed!

I feel like I tried everything on this, do you have any experience in solving similar image problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the data-src attribute, are you trying to use the [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/) system? If so, I'm guessing the problem is occurring somewhere within that system, rather than in Heroku's asset compilation. For example, if you move your image tag outside the noscript and the divs, I'm guessing it will work.

Comment: True, it was a matter of javascripts using jquery, conflicting with picturefill. They should be loaded in order through application.rb, not in the view.